# ef core context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, param1, param2) throws SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ef core version I use is :3.0 
The code I write is somehow like below:

```
SqlParameter table = new SqlParameter("@tableName", tableName);
SqlParameter entryId = new SqlParameter("@entryId", id);
string sql = "delete from @tableName where id = @entryId";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, table , entryId);
```

my sql statement have two parameters, which I have already defined and passed, but each time I execute it, i just got the following exception, please help to take a look. thanks

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the
>   table variable "@tableName".    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean
>   inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean&
>   usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache,
>   Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade, String sql, Object[] parameters)    at

Comment: With just a stacktrace and message we won't be able to help you. Besides, the message *Must declare the table variable "@tableName".* seems clear to me. What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: @PeterBons, the sql should work from the document, but i get an error, i want to know how to make it works. Thanks

Comment: Table names, column names and other sql identifiers cannot be parameterized

Comment: @CaiusJard, really? I did not found this in the Microsoft document, if so I know the reason. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Table names and column names cannot be parameterized. In C# terms this would be like putting your class name in a string and trying to instantiate it:

```
string className = "Person";
className p = new className; //it doesn't work
```

You code will have to be more like:

```
SqlParameter entryId = new SqlParameter("@entryId", id);
string sql = "delete from "+tableName+" where id = @entryId";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, entryId);
```

Do not give the end user the ability to alter the contents of the tableName variable

---

Extra info courtesy of Lutti Coelho:

To avoid SQL Injection on your query it's better to use `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` method. This method allow using string interpolation syntax in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks.

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated("delete from {tableName} where id = {id}");
```

> Always use parameterization for raw SQL queries
>
> When introducing any user-provided values into a raw SQL query, care must be taken to avoid SQL injection attacks. In addition to validating that such values don't contain invalid characters, always use parameterization which sends the values separate from the SQL text.
>
> In particular, never pass a concatenated or interpolated string ($"") with non-validated user-provided values into FromSqlRaw or ExecuteSqlRaw. The FromSqlInterpolated and ExecuteSqlInterpolated methods allow using string interpolation syntax in a way that protects against SQL injection attacks.

You can see more about raw SQL queries at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try, and yes as you mentioned the question here is that the tableName have the potential security issue, like to be injected.

Comment: If it solve your problem, please mark this answer as correct. It will help people that have the same problem in the future.

Comment: In EF Core 3.0 to avoid sql injections on your query you should use .FromSqlInterpolated($"delete from {tableName} where id = {id}") I'll edit this on the answer

Comment: @LuttiCoelho and cloud you please share an example on how to use the FromSqlInterpolated method. I mean how to pass the value of {tableName} and {id}

Comment: A simple way would be to ensure table name is in a white list of table names- FromSqlInterpolated might prevent sql injection but it ain't gonna stop a user from passing "users" and your query nuking the admin user. If there is a certain restricted set of tables that may be deleted from a whitelist would be the way to go

Comment: @CaiusJard very good point, we can have a configuration of the white list maybe. But our service is quite special, its allows the users to customize their own tables which is a real table in the database.  But I think we can still use the white list, we can update it when there is a new customize table

Comment: Ok, or black list the tables they're not allowed to delete from. Most enterprise  db have ways of querying the schema so you can always ask the db for a list of tables, except tables in the black List, to create a white list